# how to receive an type as parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

I'm writing a method that do a cast and I need receive an type as parameter, for example:

```
object foo(?? type, object input) { 

    if(type is x ) { 
       Output output = new Output();
       x xValue = (x) input; 
       foreach(var val xValue) { 
          //do.. 
       }

       return output; 
    }

    if(type is y) {
          Output2 output = new Output2();
          y yValue = (y) input; 

        foreach(var val yValue) { 
          //do.. 
        }

       return output;
    } else { 
      //invalid type
    }
}
```

Comment: Type as in `System.Type` or type as in an object of a specific (or inherited) type?

Comment: an type as `CookieCollection`, `CookieContainer`..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a *type* parameter:

```
object foo<T>(T input) {
  if (T is x) { ...
  ...
```

Also, your method is a little weird, there seems to be a lot of commonality in your branches, and testing for types is not normally a good approach. Make an effort to unify them or split the method in type-specific overloads:

```
Output foo(x input) ...

Output2 foo(y input) ...

...
```

And, try to use a more specific return type, as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you're asking:

```
object foo(System.Type type, object input) { 
...
}
```

However why don't you use different methods for each type?  What do you gain by having a monolithic method that can handle different types?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a `Type` as input where the type is the type of the `input` parameter.  If so then the easiest way is to use a generic function

```
object foo<T>(T input) {
  Type type = typeof(T);
  ...
}
```

You could even have an overload which takes the `Type` explicitly and have the generic function feed into it

```
object foo<T>(T input) {
  return foo(typeof(T), input);
}

object foo(Type type, object input) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: can you expand on this? It's exactly what I'm looking for. I'm requesting values from a dataset, and I'm asking the developer to send the type of variable to return so my return statement would be something like (returnType)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][columnName]

Comment: @ganders in that case you'd want to essentially do something like the following `T foo<T>() { return (T)...; }`